# Multiboot, Live Tiny Core and grub4dos

Tags: grub, dual-boot

I've got a usb pen drive that miraculously I installed grub4dos, and it works, I can start some iso's like MSDart, etc.

I've decided put Tiny Core Linux in the usb stick, then I downloaded the latest iso from tinycore website, xcopy the .iso to usb stick and.. it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need two files and can d/l them directly from the tinycore web site - grab the kernel, bzImage and the initrd tinycore.gz from:

http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/3.x/release/distribution_files/

Their md5 checksums are 
d1a861de33cab5b477e3bb7aa7fdd5b7  bzImage
e1b9a02d7b9fb4980d815e83883c2129  tinycore.gz

Download those and point your grub entry at them and you're in business.  Check out the tinycore forums if you need further assistance - the folks there are very helpful:
http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/

I use Tinycore on a USB pendrive all the time and it just plain works.  I use the older grub, so I can't help specifically with grub4dos but it sounds like you've got a good handle on that part.

Liam